# Limiting the available apps in Android Sharesheet

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sharing

I've done a bunch of Google, but I don't see any answers to this. My requirement is that we need to share content to Microsoft Teams, and only Teams.

Obviously we have seen that Android's Sharesheet is the go-to method for sharing content between apps, however I have not found a way to limit which apps appear in the Sharesheet.

Is there a way to limit the apps, i.e. whitelist Teams?

I'm also exploring the method of using an Intent with the Teams package name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to limit the apps, i.e. whitelist Teams?

Craft an `Intent` that limits its scope to an application ID for Teams via `setPackageName()`.

Also, when you call `startActivity()`, make sure that you wrap your call in a `try`/`catch` block and deal with the case where the user does not have that app available to them, as you will get an `ActivityNotFoundException`.

> I'm also exploring the method of using an Intent with the Teams package name.

That is your only option. It is a fragile option, insofar as Microsoft can ship as many apps described as "Teams" as Microsoft wants to. You might also see if Microsoft has a dedicated API for sharing with their Teams app(s).

Comment: Thank you for the response, we are going to give this a first pass, and I'll revert, mark it as the answer